# For simple, triangle-free graphs, prove $e(G) \le \alpha(G)\beta(G)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, solution-verification

For simple, triangle-free graphs, prove $e(G) < \alpha(G)\beta(G)$, where:

- $e(G)$ - number of edges
- $\alpha(G)$ -  independence number (maximum size of independent vertex set in G)
- $\beta(G)$ - minimum size of a vertex cover
- We'll also make use of the notation $\Delta(G)$ for maximum vertex degree in $G$

---

The way I went about it is as follows:

1. We know that since G is triangle free, the neighborhood of any vertex is an independent set and so $\Delta(G) \le \alpha(G)$.
2. Since every edge has an endpoint in a vertex cover, the sum of vertex degrees over the vertices of a vertex cover C is at least as large as number of edges in the graph: $e(G) \le \sum_{v_i \in C}{d(v_i)}$
3. In particular for a minimum vertex cover $C$ of size $\beta(G)$ we then have $$e(G) \le \sum_{v_i \in C}{d(v_i)} \le \sum_{v_i \in C}{\Delta(G)} = \beta(G)\Delta(G) \le \beta(G)\alpha(G)$$

QED. Is this right?

Comment: Seems right to me.

Comment: Looks alright to me

Comment: Appears correct to me.